# "Show in Finder" broken in my XCode 4.6?

Tags: xcode4.6

I use XCode 4.6 on OSX 10.8.2 and the "Show in Finder" Function from the right click context menu that used to work doesn't work anymore on my box. It just does nothing. I tried an XCode restart, restarting the machine, without success.

Can anyone imagine a way how this could be fixed without a fresh XCode install?

Note: Does work for my other Applications, iTunes for instance.

Comment: What were you doing when it stopped working?

Comment: @Popeye Don't know exactly. It's not a feature I use every day. But surely it worked in the 4.5 release.

Comment: Yeah it worked in the 4.5 release but it also works in the 4.6 release so I would suggest you have done something that has messed it up or it has become corrupt when updating/installing.

Comment: @Popeye Yeah I'd definitely bet I've done something that messed it up. But I have no clue what that something might be and possibly there is some more enlightened person than I am who possibly could suggest what that something possibly could be... I honestly cannot localize the point in time where it stopped working. So there is a large time window and a lot of activities. If I could pinpoint it precisely I surely would have provided that info. (I've really been doing a lot of stuff.) But maybe there is some smart guy who knows exactly that the reason can either be A or B and that would help.

Comment: Have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/479476/show-in-finder-wont-open-a-new-finder-window

Comment: @Popeye THX that worked! Make an answer and I'll give you the checkmark you desire!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the actual issue is but whilst having a look around on the superuser.exchange website I came across this https://superuser.com/questions/479476/show-in-finder-wont-open-a-new-finder-window which seems to be what your issue could be.

Glad it has helped.